# How do I read from an input file GDB and Assembly

Tags: assembly, gdb

I am trying to run gdb on an assembly program. The assembly program takes in an input file which I run via

```
cat foo.by | ./program
```

It reads through the text file, character by character, and decides what to do with the input. The thing is when I run gdb I just want the reads to come straight from the file and not have to input them every single time, that way I can set up the breakpoints and find the error quickly, without meticulously inputting each character one at a time.

Comment: `gdb ./program` then `run < foo.by`?

Comment: works, thanks a ton!!